# universal windows draw graphics and save image on the fly

Tags: android, c++, image, windows-10, win-universal-app

I am developing a Universal Windows 10 app in C++ and requirement is something like this - there is a specification of triangle/rectangle/etc. like coordinates, border width, border color, etc. Now, I need to create an image such that the specified triangle can be drawn on it and then save the image to a temporary location.

I have tried 3rd party libraries like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), but can't use it because firstly I am developing a Universal app, so it needs to be cross-platform and secondly, it is way too large a library to fit in the app.

I also looked at [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D), but it also requires a Canvas element to be put on UI. Also, drawing there needs to be done in Draw event handler, but I want to do on the fly, something like `Image2D getTriangle(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, Color color)`.

1. I looked into Android app development and they have something called "android.graphics.Paint" that can be used. Is there something in Universal Windows SDK that I can leverage?
2. I don't really want to create a XAML element. Reason - it needs to be loaded on UI before I can use it (technically, needs to go "layout pass") and I do not want to display it on screen - just save the image on disk.
3. Like Universal Windows, it should be able to run on all platforms supported by Universal Windows, like Windows Phone, Surface, PC, etc.

Comment: If you want an multi-platform software, there are plenty of drawing tools: from low-level openGL (es?) up to libraries like QT.

Comment: @AdrianMaire I actually need to generate these image for optimising texture loading at a later stage, so openGL is not an option. Also, it should be able to run on any platform supported by Universal Windows. Essentially what I'm seeking is a way to compose images without calling GL or adding on XAML.

Comment: Well, you tagged Android, which is not universal-windows if I am correct.
You want o load images, to generate images or to save images?

Comment: @AdrianMaire I tagged Android because there is "android.graphics.Paint" library that I does what I want to achieve. I want to first generate image from specification, then save it and later load it.

Comment: what about qt-Svg and qt-Image? You could probably convert your specification to xml/svg and render with qt-svg, then that could be exported to any "standard" file format.

Comment: @AdrianMaire displaying and rendering image is not what concerns me as of now. All I need to do is create an image and dump it in a file on disk programatically. Can qt-svg just silently create image of triangle from a set  of coordinate at run time and dump on disk without user interaction?

Comment: Yes of course, I never spoke about displaying to the user, just about rendering and saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got solution for my problem and hopefully it will guide others who stumble here.
The library to be used for creating images on the fly in Universal Windows App is still Win2D. But where as Direct2D writes image on screen, there is an [offscreen drawing library](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Offscreen.htm) inside Win2D that helps in drawing images to file. Essentially, we create the render target using **CanvasRenderTarget** and draw using **CanvasDrawingSession**. When done, we save the image using **SaveAsync** to disk.

Win2D is available as a nuGet package also and since it is a microsoft project with maintained .uwp package, it seems to be made to run on all platforms that Universal Windows target.

Example Code -

```
CanvasDevice^ device = CanvasDevice::GetSharedDevice();
CanvasRenderTarget^ offscreen = ref new CanvasRenderTarget(device, width, height, 96);
{
    CanvasDrawingSession^ ds = offscreen->CreateDrawingSession();
    ds->Clear(Colors::Black);
    ds->DrawRoundedRectangle(Rect (0, 0, 100, 100), 0, 0, Colors::White);
}
offscreen->SaveAsync(filepath)
```

Comment: It would be really helpful to the wup 10 community if you update your answer with some code . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could probably manage to convert your specification into xml/svg format (if not already the case) and then render and save with some of the QT library:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvgrenderer.html

> The QSvgRenderer class is used to draw the contents of SVG files

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html

> The QImage class provides a hardware-independent image representation

- Create SVG xml text with your specification
- Alternatively, paint directly your content with a QPainter
- Save the QImage in any format of your choice.

Comment: Is qt lightweight enough to make mobile apps? I already crossed out ImageMagick due to large size. Also, I am using Visual Studio to build Universal Windows app, so qt may not be suitable...

Comment: Yes, there are versions for Android as an example. Anyway, you only need the qimage & qpainter/qsvg. I would say less than 1MB